# Jmeter Response Assertion Check

Tags: jmeter

As my HTTP request has a few steps/redirects (7 redirects) , I am unable to do any 'Text Response' assertion check (text on the browser appears only in the last step/redirect of the request so it fails). Therefore, I have added a Beanshell assertion with the following code:

Subresults = SampleResult.getSubResults();String stext = (Subresults[7].getResponseDataAsString());
Failure = !stext.contains("choose the type you are looking for");
FailureMessage = "Failed to load the quote page";

but BS assertion is not as performant as JSR223? Please could someone suggest any better way OR how to translate the above 3 lines using JSR223 PostProcessor.

Thanks,
NKP

Answer (score 0):

You may re-use the majority of your code, just pass these `Failure` and `FailureMessage` object to the [AssertionResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/assertions/AssertionResult.html) shorthand, something like:

```
Subresults = SampleResult.getSubResults();
String stext = (Subresults[7].getResponseDataAsString());
Failure = !stext.contains("choose the type you are looking for");
FailureMessage = "Failed to load the quote page";

AssertionResult.setFailure(Failure);
AssertionResult.setFailureMessage(FailureMessage);
```

More information: [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)

Comment: It is throwing exception for the first line:                      
No signature of method: static org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.getSubResults() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Didn't work even after amending it to: 
SampleResult[] Subresults = SampleResult.getSubResults();

Comment: Do you have `import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult` line anywhere in your script? If you do - please remove it as I didn't mention that you need to have any imports anywhere as it causes a clash between `SampleResult` pre-defined variable and the [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance. Or just change `SampleResult` to `prev`. More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)

Comment: When I ran it after removing the import line, it complains No such property for SampleResult for class. 
If I run it with the import line after replacing SampleResult to prev, it complains No such property for AssertionResult

Comment: Use JSR223 Assertion, not the JSR223 Post-Processor

Comment: This works only when there is valid data but if the data is invalid it throws an error message 'java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 7 out of bounds for length 7' and the error message 'Failed to load the quote page' is not displayed

Comment: You asked how to translate the code from Beanshell to Groovy -> you got the answer. If you need now to fix the code to support different number of subresults - ask a new question